# SpringBoot not automatically serving static files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have SpringBoot 1.3.3 and a working Java API exposed on port 8080. However, along with this API I would like to expose an index.html file located directly under {projectName}/src/main/resources/, according to the Springboot documentation this should be served up automatically but when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/index.html I get a 404. I am not using @EnableWebMVC anywhere and have tried adding my own configuration file like below, however nothing has worked so I'm kind of at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class ServerConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {

private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the files in /src/main/resources/public/

Comment: @CodingPadawan No problem, best of luck with your project!